# cuFFT in column direction

Tags: cuda, cufft

I have a Complex matrix of nx * ny. I want to perform FFT in only column direction. One way is to transpose the entire matrix and then use cufftPlan1d to obtain FFT. Is there any other efficient way to obtain FFT without taking transpose of matrix. Will cufftPlanMany help to obtain fft in column direction. For e.g. let us assume nx = 8192 and ny = 32768. The Parameters for cufftPlanMany is as follows:

```
rank = 1;
idist = 1  // distance b/w batches
odist = 1
istride = nx
ostride = nx
int inembed[]={nx}
int onembed[]={nx}
```

cufftPlanMany(&plan,rank,ny,&inembed,istride,idist,&onembed,ostride,odist,CUFFT_C2C,1)

Is this the right way to use cufftPlanMany?

Comment: You can do this with advanced data layout.  It is described in the cufft documentation, and the usage is identical to what you would to do with fftw.

Comment: For e.g. let us assume nx = 8192 and ny = 32768. The Parameters for cufftPlanMany is as follows:

rank = 1;
idist = 1 ;
odist = 1 ;
istride = nx ;
ostride = nx;
int inembed[]={nx};
int onembed[]={nx};cufftPlanMany(&plan,rank,ny,&inembed,istride,idist,&onembed,ostride,odist,CUFFT_C2C,1)

Is this the right way to use cufftPlanMany?

Answer (score 1):

You mention batches as well as 1D, so I will assume you want to do either row-wise 1D transforms, or column-wise 1D transforms.

In this case, the number of batches is equal to the number of rows for the row-wise case or the number of columns for the column-wise case.

For 1D transforms, `inembed` and `onembed` don't really matter, but they must not be set to NULL.

The `idist`, `istride`, `odist`, and `ostride` parameters are the key ones to change for this example (along with `batch`).  Use the CUFFT [advanced data layout](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#advanced-data-layout) information.

Here is a worked example, showing row-wise and column-wise transforms:

```
$ cat t1620.cu
#include <cufft.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  cufftComplex data[] = {
    {1.0f, 0}, {2.0f, 0}, {3.0f, 0}, {4.0f, 0},
    {1.0f, 0}, {2.0f, 0}, {3.0f, 0}, {4.0f, 0},
    {1.0f, 0}, {2.0f, 0}, {3.0f, 0}, {4.0f, 0},
    {1.0f, 0}, {2.0f, 0}, {3.0f, 0}, {4.0f, 0}};
  cufftComplex *d_data;
  int ds = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, ds*sizeof(data[0]));
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, ds*sizeof(data[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cufftHandle plan;
  int dim = 4;
  int rank = 1;
  int nx = dim;
  int ny = dim;
#ifdef ROW_WISE
  int batch = ny;
  int inembed[rank] = {nx};
  int onembed[rank] = {nx};
  int istride = 1;
  int idist = nx;
  int ostride = 1;
  int odist = nx;
  int n[] = {nx};
#else
  int batch = nx;
  int inembed[rank] = {ny};
  int onembed[rank] = {ny};
  int istride = nx;
  int idist = 1;
  int ostride = nx;
  int odist = 1;
  int n[] = {ny};
#endif
  cufftResult err = cufftPlanMany(&plan, rank, n, inembed,
    istride, idist, onembed, ostride,
    odist, CUFFT_C2C, batch);
  std::cout << "plan :" << (int)err << std::endl;
  err = cufftExecC2C(plan, d_data, d_data, CUFFT_FORWARD);
  std::cout << "exec :" << (int)err << std::endl;
  cudaMemcpy(data, d_data, ds*sizeof(data[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++) std::cout << data[i].x << "," << data[i].y << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1620 t1620.cu -lcufft -DROW_WISE
$ ./t1620
plan :0
exec :0
10,0
-2,2
-2,0
-2,-2
10,0
-2,2
-2,0
-2,-2
10,0
-2,2
-2,0
-2,-2
10,0
-2,2
-2,0
-2,-2
$ nvcc -o t1620 t1620.cu -lcufft
$ ./t1620
plan :0
exec :0
4,0
8,0
12,0
16,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
$
```